Which has more legs, a Fettlepod or a Sentonium?
The contestants were lined up, each hoping to get into the Millionaire chair. First, they would need to get through the “fastest fingers first” round.
The host cleared his throat: “List these animals in order of the number of legs they have, starting with the most:”

A Fettlepod

B Eldrobe

C Sentonium

D Quizzlehatch


Guessing blindly, Jasmine went for CDBA, Virat chose CBDA and Finnbarr picked ADCB, but none got all four right. In fact, they all got the same number of answers in the correct position.
Which has more legs, a Fettlepod or a Sentonium?
Source: https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg24833142-200-puzzle-94-which-imaginary-creature-has-the-most-legs/

If everyone got the same number of right answers, then

 C is not first and A is not last. If C were first, one of the following would be true:
 - A is last, which means that one of Jasmine and Virat got two more correct than the other.
 - A is not last, which means that C is right, A is wrong, whichever answer was in A's spot is wrong, and the last question was answered correctly by one of Jasmine and Virat, and incorrectly by the other.
 (Demonstrating that A is not last follows identical logic.)


 This means that nobody got any positions right, so A is third, C is second, D is last, and B is first. A Sentonium has more legs than a Fettlepod.


DIfferent argument to conclude that nobody got any positions correct: Jasmine and Virat have 2 positions identical and 2 switched. So these two can only have either 2 in correct position or none in correct position. If they had 2 that would have to be C in first and A in fourth position. But then there is no way Finnbarr could have 2 in correct position. Therefore everyone has to have zero positions right.
